# Remove value in JSON array

Tags: python, json

This is how I add values to the JSON file.

```py
with open('data.json', 'r+') as f:
    json_datas = json.load(f)
    ids = json_datas["ids"]
    ids.append(user_id)
    json_new_datas = json.dumps({"ids": ids})
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(json_new_datas)
```

This is what the JSON file looks like:

```json
{"ids": [447737210570276875, 528619819306713089, 447428922544488449, 780750434956607488]}
```

I've tried removing values like this but it doesn't work:

```py
with open('data.json', 'r+') as f:
    json_datas = json.load(f)
    ids = json_datas["ids"]
    ids.remove(user_id)
    json_new_datas = json.dumps(json_datas)
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(json_new_datas)
```

How do I remove the `user_id`?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "it doesn't work"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not working because you're writing on top of existing content on your file, so if your array is like this:

```
{"ids": [447737210570276875, 528619819306713089, 447428922544488449, 780750434956607488]}
```

When you remove the last ID `780750434956607488`, you'll have an object like this:

```
{"ids": [447737210570276875, 528619819306713089, 447428922544488449]}
```

So when you try to write it on top of the existing file, the strings will overlap and you will have something like this:

```
{"ids": [447737210570276875, 528619819306713089, 447428922544488449]} 780750434956607488]}
```

Which breaks the file. One possible solution to your problem is to erase everything from the file first with the function `f.truncate(0)` and then write the new object :

```
with open('data.json', 'r+') as f:
    json_datas = json.load(f)
    ids = json_datas["ids"]
    ids.remove(user_id)
    f.seek(0)
    f.truncate(0)
    json_new_datas = json.dump({"ids": ids}, f)
```

Answer (score -1):

What you have is a pairing "json_datas" with key-value pair: id:[list]
the key "ids" is paired with a list.
try changing ids.remove(value) to ids.remove(index).

Besides .remove(), there's also del list[index] and splice for similar effect.
Beware, when you del, your list size gets (-1) smaller so your next del index should be adjusted

Comment: ``remove()`` removes by value, not index.